# Align two textviews so that the right one resizes until max and the left one fits in

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I need a table-like view in Android which I can fill with custom name-value rows. A row consists of two horizontally-placed text views which hold the name and the value. Every row should have the following properties:

- The left text view is aligned to parent-left, and the right one is aligned to parent-right.
- The right text never becomes longer than 7 ems, but can be smaller.
- The left text should fill up the remaining space in the row.
- Obviously, the two text views should never overlap.

Currently I'm trying to solve this with a LinearLayout as the container and two TextViews wrapped in a RelativeLayout, but something's clearly out of place here (the underlined bit is clearly longer than 7 ems):

[image]

---

My XMLs:

The row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxEms="7"
        android:maxLines="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tb2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tb2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The container layout into which the rows are added programatically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:padding="16dp"/>
```

I'm using this layout as part of a dialog. Not sure if it adds anything to the problem or not.

Any ideas/solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special, just use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` with `layout_weight`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxEms="7"
        android:maxLines="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Maybe some margin on the left of the right text would be good too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've just checked it and it seems that it keeps the left textview at the maximum of 7 ems of length, not the right one. I tried to invert it, but it doesn't work that way - the widget is still too wide and looks like on the screenshot.

Comment: I have just tested it, it works perfectly fine for both fields. Make sure you don't use maxEms together with layout_weight. That combination makes no sense, weight setting overrides all restrictions regarding the presumed width.

Answer (score 0):

it will work as per your requirements you can adjust weights

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tb2"
        android:text="nameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tb2" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxEms="7"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="valuessss"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answer are correct but you have to understand RelativeLayout align components relative to each other e.g (left,right,top,bottom) to achieved require result you have to limit second component width, there is one issue your second component will alway have fixed width even first component is empty.

LinearLayout align component the way they are presented in xml mean linearly one next to other. the weight attribute tell the layout how much space component should occupy on the screen.A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view.

Comment: Let me confirm: do you mean that the textview with the larger weight will automatically resize to take all space left out by thee textview with the smaller weight? e.g. if the smaller one has text "a", the bigger one can go beyond its size determined by weight alone?

Comment: Yes, check documentation for better understanding.

Comment: It makes perfect sense to use LinearLayout for this particular situation. Try to avoid using RelativeLayout if possible: not just harder to maintain because of the ID references, but also takes more effort from the OS to calculate the coordinates when the actual layouting is done.